# Passing pointer to thread via message_loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to encode a video, I got a green screen for the packets which I think it means I am getting empty buffer. I suspect I am passing the parameters wrong. I want help in getting the parameters passed correctly.

```
    vpx_codec_iter_t iter = NULL;
    const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt;
    // copy the pixels into our "raw input" container.
    int bytes_filled = avpicture_fill(&pic_raw, data, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, out_width, out_height);
    if(!bytes_filled) {
        Logger::Log("Cannot fill the raw input buffer");
        return;
    }

    if(vpx_codec_encode(&codec, &raw, frame_cnt, 1, flags, VPX_DL_REALTIME))
          die_codec(&codec, "Failed to encode frame");

    while( (pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(&codec, &iter)) ) {
        switch(pkt->kind) {
            case VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT:
                glb_app_thread.message_loop().PostWork(callback_factory_.NewCallback(&EncoderInstance::write_ivf_frame_header, pkt));
                glb_app_thread.message_loop().PostWork(callback_factory_.NewCallback(&EncoderInstance::WriteFile, pkt));
                break;
            default:break;
        }
    }
```

for the event handler

```
void EncoderInstance::WriteFile(int32_t result, const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt){
    lock_file_.Acquire();
    (void) fwrite(pkt->data.frame.buf, 1, pkt->data.frame.sz, outfile);
    Logger::Log("Packet written");
    lock_file_.Release();

}
```

My question is, am I passing the argument `pkt` correctly? or should I put these packets into a queue then let the `writeFile` function work on the queue.

Comment: Difficult to say, not knowing what happens in which thread. Nevertheless, my first gess would be that there is a data race on `vpx_codec_ctx_t`  between the thread populating it and the threads extracting the information.

Comment: How do you suggest I debug it? This is the first time I code something like this

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug.  First make a more comprehensive logging (log also the thread-id, so that you can see the chronology across threads.  The next step would be to put an additional lock on a mutex to protect each part of code/function where you use the risky vpx_codec_ctx_t - this might slow down throughput, as one thread only can access the struture at a time, but if it thne works you can look for another cause.

Comment: Will try that thanks

Comment: @Christophe I debugged the code but did not solve the issue yet. in the debugging I think the functions `write_ivf_frame_header` & `WriteFile` access `pkt` which is a const* that gets rewritten. 

I think the solution could be either by having a queue or a shared buffer, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, but a queue that is designed for multithreading (e.g. either the access is always protected with a mutex, or  lock-free variant).

Comment: Yes, this is what I have in mind, I will have lock and always running thread to check the queue then fwrite